# Redux - do I need to keep action types separately?

Tags: redux

I'm currently defining my action types in a separate file:

```
export const SET_SOME_ID = 'SET_SOME_ID';
export const SET_SOME_NAME = 'SET_SOME_NAME';
...
```

then in my action creators file I am doing this:

```
import * as ATYPES from './actionTypes.js';
export function setSomeId(id) {
    return { type: ATYPES.SET_SOME_ID}
}
export function setSomeName(name) {
    return { type: ATYPES.SET_SOME_NAME}
}
...
```

I feel like I should just dispense with having the action types in a separate file and just do this in the actionCreators.js file:

```
export function setSomeId(id) {
    return { type: 'SET_SOME_ID'}
}
```

Is this necessary, i.e. as the application grows will it become apparent that this was the right thing to do?

Comment: It's actually up to devs and sounds more like a best practice problem. I'll vote for your old one for a decent scale and complex project, trading some boilerplates for long term readability and maintenance. For small projects you might even don't need redux as its creator Dan said.

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* just return a string without defining the types in a separate file. However, this is bad coding practice in general - arbitrary strings, especially ones used across multiple files, should be defined as a constant variable and imported wherever used.

In your case, you have to use the action type strings within your action creators and within one or more of your reducers (multiple reducers can be set to respond to a single action type). Defining the action types as constants and import them wherever used reduces the risk of accidentally misspelling them in one of the sources in which they're used, which can cause a lot of wasted time debugging a simple bug / misspelling.

Also, its advantageous to define all of your action types as constants.. allows you and other team members to easily see the action types for possibly several action creators.

The Redux API docs more or less say it's up to you, but goes into a list of positives to defining the action types as constants:
https://redux.js.org/recipes/reducing-boilerplate#actions (right before the Action Creators section)

Comment: Also, don't forget that a good editor can autocomplete constants for you; it can't autocomplete strings.

Comment: @JordanRunning actually tabnine extension, which utilizes GPT-2 , for vscode and other, can also autocomplete strings partially or completely